# Mysql combine two results and group them by field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying but it seems I am missing something. I want to combine two results from two tables by a common field.

I would like to group results from these two queries by customer field.

```
SELECT errors.customer, count(errors.customer) as err_count,severity from errors  group by customer,severity;

SELECT customer,sum(size) as Tot_size,count(customer) as Policy_count from backup group by customer;
```

I have tried this.

```
SELECT errors.customer, count(errors.customer) as err_count,severity from errors group by customer,severity union all SELECT customer,count(customer) as Policy_count ,sum(size) as Tot_size from backup group by customer;
```

But for some reason some columns are missing.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I do not think a `UNION` is what you need...

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the requirements for `union`:

> The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.
>
> - Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns
> - The columns must also have similar data types
> - The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

Apparently, the above items are not satisfied in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT q1.customer, Tot_size, Policy_count, err_count, severity
FROM ( SELECT customer, SUM(size) AS Tot_size, COUNT(customer) AS Policy_count 
       FROM backup GROUP BY customer ) q1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT customer, COUNT(customer) AS err_count, severity
            FROM errors GROUP BY customer, severity ) q2 ON q1.costumer = q2.costumer
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query contains three columns and your second one contains two columns.
In order to use the UNION operator your two queries need to have the same amount of columns, and the columns should be compatible.

In your case the second query lacks a third column. If there is no corresponding column to use you can set a default such as

"'n/a' as severity "
if it should be textual or 
"0 as severity "
for a numerical value.

Cheers Martin